# Vuetify tabs collapse into 'more' button, if there are too many items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build an electron app with a dynamic width and the user should size the app as he prefers.

The width should affect how many "items" I can see in my navbar.

Any item that is too much should be collapsed into a `more` button.
When the width becomes larger again, the navbar should be filled up with existing items from the `more` button.

I want to prevent scrolling in the navbar. Is there a way to calculate how many items the width could fit?

Current behavior in the example below.
Every item that is too much for the width goes out of the window:

https://codepen.io/borsTiHD/pen/ExVLeBE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called v-resize in vuetify, the directive called when the page loads and whenever the page resized. I have added a function that will use the width of the screen, divide it by 100. Pushes that much item into `tab` and the rest to `more`. `tab` will be used to draw v-tabs and `more` will be used for the dropdown. Rest everything is your code.

Please see the CodePen https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/VwvxOmO?editors=1010

```
<v-card>
  <v-toolbar
    v-resize="onResize"
    color="deep-purple accent-4"
    dark
    flat
    >
    <v-tabs
      v-model="currentItem"
      fixed-tabs
      slider-color="white"
      justify-end
      row
      wrap
      >
      <v-tab
        v-for="item in tabs"
        :key="item"
        :href="'#tab-' + item"
        >
        {{ item }}
      </v-tab>

      <v-menu
        v-if="more.length"
        bottom
        left
        >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn
            text
            class="align-self-center mr-4"
            v-on="on"
            >
            more
            <v-icon right>mdi-menu-down</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-list class="grey lighten-3">
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in more"
            :key="item"
            @click="addItem(item)"
            >
            {{ item }}
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-toolbar>

  <v-tabs-items v-model="currentItem">
    <v-tab-item
      v-for="item in items.concat(more)"
      :key="item"
      :value="'tab-' + item"
      >
      <v-card flat>
        <v-card-text>
          <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
              {{ text }}
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs-items>
</v-card>
```

```
data: {
  currentItem: 'tab-Web',
  items: [
    'Web', 'Shopping', 'Videos', 'Images', 'Tab 5', 'Tab 6', 'Tab 7', 'Tab 8', 'Tab 9', 'Tab 10', 'News', 'Maps', 'Books', 'Flights', 'Apps'
  ],
  tabs: [],
  more: [],
  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
  },
  methods: {
    addItem (item) {
      const removed = this.tabs.splice(this.tabs.length-1, 1)
      this.tabs.push(
        ...this.more.splice(this.more.indexOf(item), 1)
      )
      this.more.push(...removed)
      this.$nextTick(() => { this.currentItem = 'tab-' + item })
    },
    onResize(){
      const temp = this.items.slice()
      this.tabs = temp.splice(0, (window.innerWidth/100)-1)
      this.more = temp.splice(0)
    }
  },
```

Comment: Wow, thats amazing and yet so simple. Perfect, thank you. :D